# Icon and text alignment

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I achieve this using bootstrap 3? Currently the paragraph is wrapping underneath the icon. This is what I have so far:

```
<div class="what-you-get">
    <span class="icon-stack icon-2x left">
                      <i class="icon-circle icon-stack-base bg-green"></i>
                      <i class="icon-flag icon-light"></i>
                    </span>
    <h4 class="left">The Problem</h4>
    <p class="left">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
    </p>
</div>
```

I'm using bootstrap 2.3.2 styles. http://jsbin.com/OjoYIMIM/1/edit?html,output

I can't post the image :-(

Comment: You may want to provide a JSfiddle with your code to help others see what you're talking about. What you're posting is a tiny amount of HTML with no styling, how are we supposed to help?

Comment: You should also post your CSS as that is part of your tags for this question yet you have no relevant code.

Comment: Thanks @rafaelcastrocouto for posting my issue to jsbin. In the jsbin post the text of the paragraph wraps underneath the icon. It doesn't line up with the h4 text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: http://jsbin.com/OjoYIMIM/1/edit?html,css,output

```
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] { vertical-align: baseline }
```

Comment: Need to line up the Lorem Ipsum paragraph with the h4 text and prevent the p tag from wrapping underneath the icon.

Comment: Add `h4 + p {padding-left: 20px;}` to affect just the paragraphs following an h4; or `p {padding-left: 20px;}` if you want it to apply to all paragraphs.

Comment: 22 for me! great comment broux... http://jsbin.com/OjoYIMIM/2/edit?html,css,output